# Prevent CheckBox check when clicking it's text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, user-controls

In other words, I want it so when you click the text on the checkbox it doesn't get checked. It only checks when you click the actual checkbox. I've tried many things, but have come up empty. It seems it will fire all the events no matter what. (Click, Checked, Focus) Maybe a way to prevent or override the default event functions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you use JQuery? preventDefault() is a nice thing...

Comment: Silverlight or Asp.Net or both?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing the text in the checkbox control itself, add a label next to it with the caption.

So you would have:

[label caption] []

Clicking on the label caption would have no effect on the checkbox.

Comment: I like this solution better than mine, actually.

Comment: But the CheckBoxes being added dynamically to a ListBox. And I need the name of the CheckBox for other things.

Comment: Why not try adding a StackPanel to the listbox? The StackPanel would have horizontal orientation with the label and checkbox. And by name of the checkbox you mean the text inside of it? You can use the 'tag' property of checkbox to store any kind of data that would not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a label's for attribute to point at the checkbox id is what causes the checkbox to get selected when the text is clicked.

```
<label for="checkboxId">test</label><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxId"/>
```

So, you could just remove the for attribute, but this is inadvisable from an accessibility perspective

Comment: You could leave the Text propery of the CheckBox control blank and set the text separately i.e. `<asp:CheckBox runat="server"/>Some Text` instead of `<asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="Some Text"/>`